# Unhandled Exception Error inserting record into SQL Database using VB

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

My code is causing this error when trying add a record in the database:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near ','

The error is pointing to this line in my code. I am selecting a date using `MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString` and inserting it into my database.

I thought it had to do with the date format, so I changed the date column format on my tables in the database from date to string and it not help. Also tried different formats for the date format was different to that from my client - made them the same to no avail.

This SQL is working.

```
INSERT INTO Event_Booking (Client_ID, Event_Name, Event_Status, No_of_People, Booking_Location, Event_Time_ID, Booking_Date)
VALUES (@Client_ID, @Event_Name, @Event_Status, @No_of_People, @Booking_Location, @Event_Time_ID, @Booking_Date);    

SELECT 
    (Event_ID, Client_ID, Event_Name, Event_Status, No_of_People, , 
     Booking_Location, Event_Time_ID, Booking_Date) 
FROM 
    Event_Booking 
WHERE 
    (Event_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY())
```

This code is not working with the error at the line marked **

```
Private Sub Button9_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click

        ***Insert A New Booking 
        Event_BookingTableAdapter.InsertNewBooking(TextBox5.Text, TextBox20.Text, TextBox21.Text, TextBox6.Text, TextBox4.Text, TimeSlotComboBox.SelectedValue, MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString)***

    End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure that SQL is working? `..No_of_People, , 
     Booking_Location...`

Comment: P.S. you might want to look in to the [`OUTPUT` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Hi Gvee, yes the SQL is working. do you see an error in it

Comment: Yes - the snippet in my first comment shows that there's two commas in a row - this is not valid. Have you missed a column name between the commas, or is this a mistype?

Comment: I see what you are referring to - i will check syntax of SQL at that point and run again

Comment: its a mistype in the SQL - not a missed column

Comment: Gvee, Ive removed the extra comma, but Im still getting the same error. Could you clarify what you meant by check the Output

Comment: I have solved the problem. I had omitted dbo from the table prefix on the in a query